# Flash AS3 | Pan / Zoom with mouse input

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, zooming, mouse, pan

I was looking to see if someone can help me figure out how to create a panning effect over an already playing video in Flash AS3, where the camera is directed by where the mouse is.

For example, this game here http://www.kongregate.com/games/jorjeade/seven-deadly-sins (skip the intro to get to it quickly) has an over world map which pans around by using the mouse. I'm trying to achieve a similar effect for my flash video.

Any help coding this would be awesome! I'm also looking to see if I can get a basic zoom function working alongside this panning, also something that the user can control though the keyboard or similar.

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Comment: Can you just make the movie clip's x and y coordinates be an inverse function of where the mouse is on the stage?

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give it a try! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For my code to work as it is, set your movie clip anchor point to "centered."

```
myMovieClip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;  
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, panFunction);
private function panFunction(me:MouseEvent):void {
    myMovieClip.x = stage.stageWidth/2 - (stage.mouseX - stage.stageWidth/2);
}
```

This will give a 1 to 1 motion that updates immediately with the mouse. You can throw in some multipliers or easing effect if you want, but hopefully this gets you going the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate that. I will certainly be trying this out, but I should be able to get it to work. My issue comes from not actually knowing where to start, tampering with code is generally fine for me.

Comment: If you can, post the code that worked as a new answer so others can benefit, or mark it if this one worked.

Comment: Will do once I get around to it! University got me busy at the moment haha