# Flash AS3 | Creation of a Camera / Moving Viewport / Zoom

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was looking to extend on a question I asked earlier here:

[Flash AS3 | Pan / Zoom with mouse input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239283/flash-as3-pan-zoom-with-mouse-input)

The basis now is that with that solution working, I am looking to improve my process much more to achieve a higher quality result.

What I am asking for here is if someone could help me find a way to make it so that the 'viewport' (what is displayed on screen) is tied to or follows an object around. Just like pointing the scope of a sniper rifle for example, you see the image through what is essentially a HUD, and you see different parts of the image as that HUD moves around.

Alongside this, is there any way for me to implement a zoom feature? My only guess is to enlarge the actual displayed image itself, so any help on this would be really great!

Thanks once again guys!

Comment: If the other **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37242829/2057709)** gave you a working solution you should mark that as correct.

Comment: PS: Yes for zoom you'll have to enlarge (look up `scaleX` & `scaleY`). For masking, create a MovieClip containing a radial gradient (white centre going outwards to black) and then use a `blendMode` like "Multiply" or possibly "Overlay". Add the gradient MC to stage after image to put it above. It should show image like thru a scope. Try that and see what you think of result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one way to achieve the effect you're looking for is to take all the content that you want to have on the screen and put it inside a MovieClip. Then, when you have a name for that MovieClip, you can adjust where it's positioned so that it's focused around one object, which would look something like this:

```
holder.x = screenWidth/2 - holder.object.x;
holder.y = screenHeight/2 - holder.object.y;
```

This little bit of math takes the object's position relative to the `holder` MovieClip and adjusts it so that the whole MovieClip is moved, putting that spot in the center.

Once you have it there, you can zoom by adjusting the `scaleX` and `scaleY` of the `holder` MovieClip, 1 is the default value for both so a 200% zoom would be 2 and so on. However, the MovieClip will zoom from the anchor point, not from the center of the screen, so you may have to move the MovieClip anytime that you want to scale it.